# I want to use a dropdown menu that will change the bgColor of the document using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, switch-statement

I am looking to use a switch and an array to change the bgColor of a document using javascript and html.

Here is my code:

```
function changebg() {

    var colors = ["red", "blue", "pink", "orange", "yellow", "green"];
    x = document.bgColor
    y = document.getElementById("selection").value;

    switch (y) {

        case "red":
            x = colors[0];
            break;

        case "blue":
            x = colors[1];
            break;

        case "pink":
            x = colors[2];
            break;

        case "orange":
            x = colors[3];
            break;

        case "yellow":
            x = colors[4];
            break;

        case "green":
            x = colors[5];
            break;

    }

}

document.bgColor = changebg();
```

Not sure where to go from here, any suggestions?

Comment: You need to return the value from `changebg` function

Comment: Don't use [bgColor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/bgColor), it's deprecated. Use `document.style.backgroundColor` instead. Or better yet, add a CSS class

Comment: Is the "use a `switch` and an array" mandate here?

Comment: Changing from bgColor to document.style.backgroundColor worked perfectly. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ho18Luh8/5/) for you. Is this what you looking for?

You just have to add this `document.body.style.backgroundColor = x;` to your function.

You can delete the switch and just use the value from the select element. It will be the cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

`return x` at the end of `changebg()`.

Answer (score 0):

For **starter** you can try this:

```js
document.getElementById("selection").addEventListener("change",function(){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor=this.value;
},false);
```

```html
<select size="1" id="selection">
    <option value="">Select a color</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
<select>
```

Points:

- use `value` attribute in `<option>`;
- use [`document.body.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style).[`backgroundColor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) (or [`document.body.className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className)/[`document.body.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)) instead of `document.bgColor`.